# post nested json object along with serialized form

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json string that looks like

```
[{"tagid":"1","name":"scandalous"},{"tagid":"4","name":"finance"}]
```

The form is being serialised on submit

```
var datastring=$(this).serializeArray();
```

I need to post the json string as tagsArray along with the form so that I can access it as

```
$_POST['tagsArray'] then json decode it so it can be looped through.
```

Help Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.stringify()

```
var data = JSON.stringify([{"tagid":"1","name":"scandalous"},
                           {"tagid":"4","name":"finance"}]);


$.ajax({  
  url: "/path/to/url",  
  type: "POST",  
  dataType: "json",  
  contentType: "json",  
  data: data,  
  success: function(){              
    alert("success :-)");  
  },  
  error: function(){  
    alert("fail :-(");  
  }  
});
```

I wrote an extension for serializing a form using JSON:

```
$.extend({
    formSerializer: new function () {
        var _self = this;
        _self.jsonSerialize = function (form) {
            var _data = {};
            var _items = form.serializeArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < _items.length; i++)
                _data[_items[i].name] = _items[i].value;
            return _data;
        };
    },
});
```

Having this extension you can do this:

```
var form = $(this);
var data = $.formSerializer.jsonSerialize(form);

    data.anotherArray = [{"tagid":"1","name":"scandalous"},
                           {"tagid":"4","name":"finance"}];

$.ajax({  
  url: "/path/to/url",  
  type: "POST",  
  dataType: "json",  
  contentType: "json",  
  data: data,  
  success: function(){              
    alert("success :-)");  
  },  
  error: function(){  
    alert("fail :-(");  
  }  
});
```

Comment: That should probably mean JSON.stringify

Comment: I need to send it along with the formdata that is serialized.
so I have all my other fields firstname, lastname etc and then the variable containing the tagsArray

Comment: You can't do it serializing the form, you have to send all fields in JSON format as a single JSON object